# Why is there the Proxy «apply» trap in JS?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

[Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) looks like an API to extend the way we can manipulate objects such as a making single getter for all properties. There is a Proxy trap called [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy/handler/apply) that interferes a function call. According to the documentation, this trap can be used only with functions so this trap can be implemented with a plain old JavaScript code without Proxy:

```js
// Proxy method
const trappedFunction = new Proxy(originalFunction, {
  apply: function(target, thisArg, argumentsList) {
    console.log(thisArg, argumentsList);
    return target.apply(thisArg, argumentsList);
  }
});

// Higher order function method
var trappedFunction = function () {
  console.log(this, arguments);
  return originalFunction.apply(this, arguments);
};
```

As far as I know, the implementations above are identical (except the [arguments](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) value that isn't an array but can be easily converted to array).

Are the implementations really identical? Why does the "apply" trap exist? What can it give compared to the plain higher order function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are the implementations really identical?

I can't see any difference between them as far as runtime behavior, other than the `arguments`-object difference. I'd personally instead do

```
var trappedFunction = function (...args) {
  console.log(this, args);
  originalFunction.apply(this, args);
};
```

to avoid `arguments` anyway.

> Why does the "apply" trap exist? What can it give compared to the plain higher order function?

Because you might want to use the other traps at the same time. There's no way to create a higher-order function that is *also* a proxy. You could technically create a higher-order function and then wrap that with a proxy but that would get complicated quickly I imagine, and then you're splitting your trap-like behavior between a proxy handler and function-wrapping logic, where an `apply` trap along with all the rest keeps things cleanly associated.

I'd also add that unless you absolutely *know* that you really *must* to use a proxy and can make your proxy behave just like the original object, which is a lot harder than you think, I'd stick with the higher-order function approach.

> Proxy was introduced to give us object access possibilities that wasn't available before such as a single getter for any property.

Personally I'd push back on this definition. `Proxy` was introduced to allow for JS code to implement the behavior of a JS object itself. As a side-effect, that means that JS code needs to be able to intercept accesses to all properties, even if they don't exist, but I'd hesitate to call that the reason it was introduced. The underlying "trap"-handler approach was already defined in ECMAScript specification and JS engines already had them internally exposed to allow C++ to define how a JS object behaved, for any builtin browser APIs and things. `Proxy` exposes those same hooks to JS itself to allow for JS itself to implement any API you could have otherwise only implemented in C++.

Comment: You are right, I can't know why Proxy was given us, I can only say what benefits it gives me. I used `arguments` to highlight that this approach is very old.

Answer (score 2):

No, they are not identical. Your first `trappedFuncton` is a proxy for `originalFunction`, which means that it behaves exactly like `originalFunction`, apart from its identity and the intercepted operations (which logs arguments and drops the return value from calls, in your example).

The second `trappedFunction` is a completely separate function object, whose only similarity to `originalFunction` is that it does the same thing when called. But `trappedFunction.prototype != originalFunction.prototype`, and many more.

Comment: _«is a completely separate function object»_ what does it affect? The `originalFunction` prototype value can be set to the `trappedFunction` prototype during the initialization and their prototypes will be identical so I still see nothing I can't do with HOF in terms of a function call intercepting (from you answer).